# I tried npm run start using react 18 and i got this error

Tags: reactjs

> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
> at module.exports (C:\Users\akins\React projects\tut-1\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\akins\React projects\tut-1\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
> at C:\Users\akins\React projects\tut-1\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
> at C:\Users\akins\React projects\tut-1\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
> at C:\Users\akins\React projects\tut-1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
> at C:\Users\akins\React projects\tut-1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
> at context.callback (C:\Users\akins\React projects\tut-1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
> at C:\Users\akins\React projects\tut-1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
> library: 'digital envelope routines',
> reason: 'unsupported',
> code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

My dependencies are:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
```

For the development server to load

Comment: The version of node you are running here is extremely important.